# Add method selector into a dictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to add a selector into a dictionary (the main purpose is for identifying the callback method and delegate after finish doing something)

But I find that I can not do that, the program will get an error "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".
Are there any other way for me to add that method selector to a dictionary?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Adding a new entry to a dictionary does two things (in addition to adding it to the dictionary, obviously):

1. It takes a copy of the key value. This means that the the key object must implement the `NSCopying` protocol
2. `retain`s the value. This means that it needs to implement the `NSObject` protocol

It's probably the second that's causing your `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

There are at least two ways around this.

Firstly, rather than adding the selector you could add the instance of the class that implements the selector to your dictionary. Usually your class will inherit from `NSObject` and it will work fine. Note that it will retain the class though, maybe not what you want.

Secondly, you can convert a selector to a string (and back again) using `NSSelectorFromString` and `NSStringFromSelector` ([docs are here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-SW13)).

Comment: Not implementing a method does not cause an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. You get a "does not recognize selector" error. Rather, the problem is the fact that selectors are not objects at all.

Comment: @user102008 Yes, it crashes because they're not objects. But it still wouldn't work correctly if the objects didn't implement `retain` and `release`.

Answer (score 36):

I know this question was answered a long time ago, but just in case anyone stumbles upon it like I did...

The combination of `NSStringFromSelector` and `NSSelectorFromString` as answered above is probably the best way to go.  But if you really want to, you *can* use a selector as a value or key in an `NSDictionary`.

A selector (type `SEL`) is implemented as a pointer to a struct in Apple's Objective-C runtimes.  A pointer cannot be used directly in a dictionary, but a pointer can be wrapped in an `NSValue` object that can be used.

Using this method you can store a selector as a value in a dictionary using code like this:

```
dictionary = 
  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSValue valueWithPointer:selector]
                              forKey:key];
```

A selector can be retrieved using code like this:

```
SEL selector = [[dictionary objectForKey:key] pointerValue];
```

Similarly for using a selector as a key:

```
dictionary = 
  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:value
                              forKey:[NSValue valueWithPointer:selector]];

value = [dictionary objectForKey:[NSValue valueWithPointer:selector]];
```

Comment: +1 using this method to store the key is more efficient than converting it to a string because pointer comparison is O(1) while string comparison is O(n)

Answer (score 2):

I get my answer based on the comment of Zydeco:

> You can convert between SEL and
>   NSString using NSSelectorFromString
>   and NSStringFromSelector

Answer (score 1):

The common idiom in Obj-C is to have specific names for callbacks for specific events. (Such `parserDidBeginDocument:` from `NSXMLParserDelegate`). If you *really* need to be able to specify the names, it is likely that your only recourse is to add the names of the selectors as `@"mySelector:withArgument:context:"` or somesuch.

Comment: You can convert between SEL and NSString using NSSelectorFromString and NSStringFromSelector

Comment: I use an singleton object for access the internet. and I have a method name: "getFooWithDelegate:callbackSelector:" and i want to add the delegate and callback to a dictionary of requests using an request UUID as the key.
Can you explain more about adding the "name of the selector" you mentioned?

Comment: @athanhcong: again; it really does sound as if you should have a single specific name for the selector in question, e.g. `internetConnection:receivedFoo:withUUID:`, since you'll have to write the receiving method for receiving the object pretty specifically anyway. If that for whatever reason isn't an option; you would use `NSSelectorFromString()` and `NSStringFromSelector()` as outlined in Stephen Darlingtons post.

Comment: In my case, I use a third party library so I don't have the choice to implement the method name like you suggest (internetConnection:receivedFoo:withUUID:). The method: NSSelectorFromString() and NSStringFromSelector() work perfectly to me. Thank both of you a lot.