# iOS Adding Method name to NSDictionary and calling it afterwards

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I am trying this thing but can't seem to get it right.. i have a `NSMutableDictionary` named **dataDictionary** with **2 KeyValue** pairs, `Id` and `MethodName`

```
NSMutableDictionary *dataDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
[dataDictionary setValue:@"1.0" forKey:@"Id"];
[dataDictionary setValue:@"myMethod" forKey:@"MethodName"];
```

while my method is

```
-(void)myMethod{ … }
```

So What i need to do is get the method name `[dataDictionary valueForKey:@"MethodName"];` and call that method…

any help would be great.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of "Vijay-Apple-Dev.blogspot.com"'s answer, did some modification to it to solve the warning..

```
NSString *myMethodInStringFormat = [dataDictionary valueForKey:@"MethodName"];

SEL mySelector = NSSelectorFromString(myMethodInStringFormat);

if (mySelector!=nil) {

        [self performSelector:mySelector withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can store it like a `NSString` using [NSSelectorFromString](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSelectorFromString) or [NSStringFromSelector](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSStringFromSelector)

or like a `NSValue`

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                       [NSValue valueWithPointer:@selector(foo)], @"foo",
                       nil];

SEL aSel = [[dict objectForKey:@"foo"] pointerValue];
```

More info:
[Add method selector into a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175818/add-method-selector-into-a-dictionary),
[Store selector as value in an NSDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822602/store-selector-as-value-in-an-nsdictionary)

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *myMethodInStringFormat=[dataDictionary valueForKey:@"MethodName"];

SEL mySelector=NSSelectorFromString(myMethodInStringFormat);


#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"

if (mySelector!=nil) {

        [self performSelector:mySelector];
}


#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Comment: nyc… but its giving a memory leak error `PerformSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown`

Comment: Changing the `performSelector` line to `[self performSelector:mySelector withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];` removed 
the warning